# Сложные объекты, проблема с влиянием друг на друга. Как их составлять?

Tags: ооп, архитектура, solid

Регулярно возникают проблемы со сложными объектами.
Не совсем понимаю как организовывать из взаимодействие.
Предположим есть планета.

```
Империя
    Планета
        Колония
            Промышленность, СельскоеХозяйство, Население, Инфраструктура
```

- У империи есть влияние на промышленность и сельское хозяйство(законы,
  транспорт и т.д).
- У Планеты есть влияние на промышленность и сельское
  хозяйство(климат, животные, недра).
- У населения есть влияние на
  промышленность и сельское хозяйство(занятость).
- У сельского хозяйства есть влияние на население(колонисты кушают)
- Инфраструктура оказывает влияние на промышленность и сельское хозяйство

Что не делаю всё херь какая то.
Возникают вопросы.

Должны ли нижестоящие классы знать о вышестоящих? Ведь чтобы посчитать продуктивность промышленности класс `Промышленность` должен знать о `Колония`, `Планета`, `Империя`, `Население` и `Инфраструктура`, а это значит, что класс `Колония` должен знать про `Планета` и `Империя`.

Надо ли тут нарушать "закон Деметры"? Должны ли нижестоящие классы знать о вышестоящих? Как решать такие задачи по принципам SOLID?

Comment: Обычно стараются делать изменения в рамках ближайших уровней. Империя знает про планеты и влияет на них. Налог например. Планета в свою очередь прокидывает налог на колонии. Колонии самостоятельно разбираются с собственными подчиненными структурами. И обратно так же. Население отдает налог колонии, та отдает планете, та - империи.

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что составил на бумаге список компетенций и список разрешений для каждого класса, какая минимальная и максимальная информация нужна каждому. Возможно, наилучшим подходом окажется класс для связи между объектами разных классов, который будет единственный знать, что нужно взаимодействующим объектам. А, возможно, - потребуется иерархия

Comment: `Промышленность должен знать о Колония, Планета, Империя`, `класс Колония должен знать про Планета и Империя` - с чего бы это? чтобы считать продуктивность, достаточно пройтись в цикле по объектам родительского типа..... так если есть тип транспорт→наземный→тяжелый→авто, то пробегаем по типу "транспорт" в котором например есть поле `count`, а т.к. авто унаследовано по цепочке, то оно там тоже будет.. нужно выделить общее свойство, составить правильную иерархию